# Rich text Area Issue- Apostrophe converting to some html tags

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller, richtextarea

How to remove the html tags and get the original content in lightning because in classic it appears correctly but when i switch to Lighting it is adding &" something whenever i am writting **"isn't"** , it is replacing it to ampersand#39Colon

Please help me with the code to replace because I have tried to replace it with replaceAll by component.set(); but it did not work. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Where are you setting it? Rich text area content if set in `aura:html` should take care of those tags automatically.

Comment: I am setting under the helper method.

Comment: I meant what is your UI tag under which this rich text are is used, please share some code snippet to better understand the scenario.

Comment: Actually its a managed package so there are lots of complex components inside components so i thought to changes it directly from js. is that not possible? because i tried to set the text with something else and it did so the only thing i am unable to do it is when i use apostrophe then it should replace everything